# Iam trying to get current location updates for every 5 minutes and send to server

Tags: android, react-native, performance, android-studio, android-layout

Iam trying to get current location updates for every 5 minutes and send to server but I am getting it in the foreground but  I am not getting it on the background

I used Alarm Manager

Comment: What? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I use this code :

```
       mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
       mLocationRequest.setInterval(60*1000);
       mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(10*1000); 
       mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

     if (mLocationCallback == null)
        mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
               if (locationResult == null) {
                    return;
                }
                for (Location location : locationResult.getLocations()) {
                     if (location != null) {
                        if(BuildConfig.DEBUG)                                   
                         mLastLocation = location;
                     }
                }
             }
         };
 

     fusedLocationProviderClient =  LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(MasterApplica tion.getInstance().getApplicationContext());
     fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationR equest, mLocationCallback, Looper.getMainLooper());
```